# Зачем передавать null в myFunction.apply?

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction(w, x, y, z) {
  console.log(w + x + y + z);
}

var args = [1, 2, 3];
myFunction.apply(null, args.concat(4));
```

Answer (score 5):

Метод `apply` вызывает функцию с явным указанием контекста (`this`), но так как внутри функции `this` нигде не используется, то результат будет одинаков для любого значения аргумента, в том числе и для `null`. К тому же вариант с `null` наиболее семантически правилен: мы как бы говорим, что нам ничего не требуется в качестве `this`.

---

Кстати, начиная с ES6, то же самое можно получить, используя так называемый spread-оператор, который записывается в виде многоточия (`...`):

```js
function myFunction(w, x, y, z) {
  console.log(w + x + y + z);
}

var args = [1, 2, 3];
myFunction(...args.concat(4));
```

Comment: "Метод apply вызывает функцию с явным указанием контекста (this), но так как внутри функции this нигде не используется, то результат будет одинаков для любого значения аргумента, в том числе и для null" - это часть не понятна, разъясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply